# Web Scraping - Access elements using css selector in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am a beginner in web scraping in python and I'm stuck on this:
How do I access the title text inside this div tag using a css selector?

```
<div class="p13n-sc-truncated selectorgadget_suggested" aria-hidden="true" data-rows="1" title="Ikigai: The Japanese secret to a long and happy life">Ikigai: The Japanese secret to a long and… </div>
```

I tried below code but did not work:

```
title = response.css('.p13n-sc-truncated::attr[title]').extract()
```

Comment: Can you provide more details about your code / library you're using ?

Comment: I am using scrapy

Answer (score 0):

You used square brackets instead of round brackets:

```py
In [1]: response.css('.p13n-sc-truncated::attr(title)').extract()
Out[1]: ['Ikigai: The Japanese secret to a long and happy life']
```